# Trim to the nearest word under limit

Tags: javascript, performance, strings, programming-challenge

Given a text and the length limit I need to trim the text to the word which is nearest to the limit.

```
function trim(text, limit) {
  if (text.length < limit) return text;

  let end = -1;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < limit - 1; i++) {
    let current = text.charAt(i);
    let next = text.charAt(i + 1);
    if (current !== ' ' && next === ' ') {
      end = i;
    }
  }
  if (i === text.length - 1) {
    end = i;
  }

  return text.substring(0, end + 1);
}

[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 50].forEach((limit) => {
  console.log(trim('Hello World', limit));
});
```

O/P:

```
//


Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello World
Hello World
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current code has a bug when the limit is exactly is exactly the length of a word. For example,

```
trim('Hello World', 5)
```

will return an empty string, when it should return `"Hello"`, since it is of length 5, therefore it fits in the length limit.

The issue stems from the loop over `i` going from 0 to `limit - 1` (excluded). The variable `end` represents the index of the last character to keep in the string, (because the method is returning `text.substring(0, end + 1)`). Therefore, it could be the case that `end` is equal to `limit - 1`, this happens when the limit falls right before a space. For example, when the limit is 5, and the string is `'Hello World'`, the last character to keep is `'o'` at index 4. So the loop should go up to `limit` (excluded).

Then, there are slight adjustements to make:

- The early-return testing `text.length < limit` should be `text.length <= limit` (because otherwise the `next` character in the loop over `i` won't exist for the last character of the string);
- The added check `if (i === text.length - 1)` can safely be removed as a consequence: the only case where `i` would be equal to `text.length - 1` is if `limit == text.length` (since `i` goes up to `limit - 1` included). But that was already handled with the modified early-return.

---

There is a simpler and efficient way to tackle this problem, using the built-in [`lastIndexOf(searchValue, fromIndex)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf). This method starts at the specified `fromIndex`, and searches backwards the first occurence of the given value. If we tell it to search the first occurence of `' '` searching backwards from `limit`, we'll exactly have the length of the substring to return.

The only corner case is if `limit` is greater than the length of the string, in which case the method should simply return the text unchanged (like the current code is doing). It needs to be tested separately; otherwise `lastIndexOf` would start searching from the end of the string, and the last word would always be cut. This is what it could look like:

```js
function trim(text, limit) {
  if (limit >= text.length) {
    return text;
  }
  return text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(' ', limit));
}

[0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 50].forEach((limit) => {
  console.log(limit + ' -> ' + trim('Hello World', limit));
});
```

Note that, even if the `lastIndexOf` call returns `-1`, because there was no space character found before the limit length, it is still safe to call [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) since:

> If either argument is less than 0 [...], it is treated as if it were 0.

Comment: If you could help me with reducing off by one errors it would be good, do you have some method to avoid that? because I spend a considerable amount of time handling that.

Comment: @CodeYogi Fair enough. I edited with the issues.

Comment: What if I have replicate the same logic in ruby since I find no such method in it?

Comment: @CodeYogi I'm afraid I do not know Ruby at all... From what I searched, perhaps a combination of [substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184697/how-to-get-a-substring-of-text) and [rindex](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/rindex).